# Не могу мигрировать бд на сервере prisma

Tags: node.js, nestjs, prisma

у меня в сервере создан база на mysql и зашёл на него но не могу сделать миграцию в терминале

сервер timeweb cloud

мой .env файл

`DATABASE_URL="mysql://username:password@212.113.122.159:3306/default_db"`

мой scheme.prisma

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "mysql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}
```

выполняю команду

```
npx prisma migrate dev --name init
```

получаю ошибку
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

но с этими же паролями я сделал логин на базу который в сервере они 100% верны

Answer (score 0):

Я надеюсь, что ты просто не захотел показывать нам свой логин и пароль, по этому показал:

> DATABASE_URL="mysql://username:password@212.113.122.159:3306/default_db"

Иначе, настоятельно рекомендую, поглубиться в изучение баз данных больше.

Человек, под которым ты, с помощью prisma, заходишь в mysql, не имеет прав на создание базы данных.

1. Зайди в mysql под главным юзером через терминал, если у тебя Ubuntu, то напиши `sudo mysql`.
2. Теперь предоставь все права, или же права юзера над базой, через `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES`. Если ты хочешь, что бы юзер под каким ты регистрируешься имел доступ ко всём возможностям mysql, то напиши

> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'newuser'@'212.113.122.159';

Вместо newUser - вставь своего юзера.

3. Сделай, что бы изменения вступили в силу:

> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

Первый раз отвечаю, может что-то не правильно обьяснил, или не понял вопрос. За ранее, извиняюсь.